# SQL show orders where 2 values are distinct and match the first

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking for a way to let me select all orders that have multiple distinct names within the same order-number, it looks like this:

```
order - name
111-Paul
112-Paula 
113-John
113-John
113-Jessica 
114-Eric
114-Eric
114-John
115-Zack
115-Zack
115-Zack
```

etc.

so that i would get all the orders that have 2 or more distinct names in it:

```
113-John
113-Jessica
114-Eric
114-John
```

with which I could do further queries but I'm stuck. Can anyone give me some hints on how to tackle this problem please? I've tried it with count(*) which looked like this:

```
select order, name, count(name) from dbo.orders
group by order, name
having count(name) > 1
```

which gave me all the orders which had more than 1 name in it but I don't know how to let it only show orders with the distinct names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using `exists`:

```
select distinct [order], name 
from orders o
where exists (
  select 1 
  from orders o2
  where o.[order] = o2.[order] and o.name != o2.name)
```

- [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87063/2)

Comment: This works flawlessly, I need some time to digest this. i didnt know you could do stuff like this. Thank you very much. Need to try the other answers as well. Thank you for helping a newbie out!

Comment: @Fantajim No worries, glad it helped.  There are several approaches to this type of question.  I just prefer using `exists` which uses a `correlated subquery` -- one where the inner query can reference the outer query.  In this case, making sure the `order` is the same, but the `name` isn't.  Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

I would use windows functions for this

For example:

```
select distinct order 
from 
    (select 
         order, 
         row_number() over(partition by order, name order by order asc) as rn
    ) as t1 
where rn > 1
```

you can do the same with count

```
count(*) over(partition by order,name order by order asc) as cnt
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like this but didn't know a:) it was possible and b:) how it was called. You helped me a lot with this. Thank you Arik

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a straight forward implementation in Sql Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9191a/1/0):

```
select distinct *
from table1
where [order] in (
    select [order]
    from (select distinct * from table1) iq
    group by [order]
    having count(*) > 1)
```

It's essentially breaking down the problem into:

1. Finding the orders that have more than one distinct value.
2. Finding the pairs of distinct order - name that belong to the list previously calculated.

Comment: This is really straight forward, Thanks for this

Comment: Sometimes simplicity is best, and internally it's using a lazy spool (you can see the execution plan straight from sql-fiddle) so it's as efficient as any of the others :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `HAVING COUNT(name) > 1`, it is counting all of the rows in those groups, including duplicate rows (rows 113-John and 113-John are 2 rows for order 113). I would query distinct rows from your table, and then select from that:

```
SELECT [order], [name] FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [order], [name] FROM dbo.orders
) A
GROUP BY [order], [name]
HAVING COUNT([name]) > 1
```

As a note, if a [name] is null, then it will not be counted with `COUNT(name)`. If you want nulls to be counted, use `COUNT(*)` instead.

Comment: Well thank you for explaining the difference, you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count(distinct name)` to get the number of unique names for each order:

```
select [order], count(distinct name)
from orders
group by [order]
```

To just get the order for those you can use `having`:

```
select [order]
from orders
group by [order]
having count(distinct name) > 1
```

To get the details for those orders you can put that in the where clause to just return the rows with `order` in that list:

```
select *
from orders
where [order] in (
  select [order]
  from orders
  group by [order]
  having count(distinct name) > 1
)
```

[*sqlfiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/744fc4/4)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer a beginner. Well structured and explained. I learned from this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would use RANK (or DENSE_RANK) for this as shown below.

```
SELECT [Order]
FROM (SELECT 
        [Order],
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [Order] ORDER BY Name) AS NameRank
      FROM [StackOverflow].[dbo].[OrderAndName]) ranked
WHERE ranked.NameRank > 1
GROUP BY [Order]
```

The sub-query ranks (gives a seeding) to the names in an order according to their value. Names with the same value would have the same rank i.e. when an order has one name multiple times (like 115) the rank of all names would be 1.

The partition is important here as otherwise you would get the rank for all names for all orders which wouldn't give you the result you'd like.

It is then just a case of pulling out the orders that have a RANK greater than 1 and grouping (could use distinct if that's a preference).

You can then join to this table to get get the orders and names as follows;

```
SELECT oan.[Order], [Name]
FROM [StackOverflow].[dbo].[OrderAndName] oan
    INNER JOIN (SELECT [Order]
                FROM (SELECT [Order],
                        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [Order] ORDER BY Name) AS NameRank
                      FROM [StackOverflow].[dbo].[OrderAndName]) ranked
                WHERE ranked.NameRank > 1
                GROUP BY [Order]) twoOrMore ON oan.[Order] = twoOrMore.[Order]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time to explain what you did there Malcolm. I need some time to fully grasp it but i already see the potential uses for this. Thanks!